# How to add an image in an email but not as an attachment?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, email

This is a more `HTML` based question then `iOS`-specific but how would you add a *local* image to an email’s body without having to attach it as an attachment? Is it technically possible?

Thank you very for your answers!

Comment: This might not answer your question, but might come in handy if you're working with e-mails: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do what you're asking is by encoding the image as a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). This includes a Base64-encoded version of your image, which you can use as the `src` of an `<img>` tag. The URI itself will look something like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC`. Note that larger images will have *much* larger URIs, so this is really only suitable for very small images.

Comment: Thanks I heard of that but wasn't really sure but is this HTML5?

Comment: It's unrelated to HTML5. That's like saying "are http:// URLs HTML5?" But all major browser engines support data URIs.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! Just found a base64 encoder so all neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the email as an HTML, and send the image as a normal `img` tag.

And of course, local images won't work. The image needs to be hosted on a server.